# Bing Maps - REST imagery API draw line limitations

Tags: .net, bing-maps

**Problem:**

When using a **POST** to create pushpins and draw lines it only works if I draw up to 62 lines.

**Why Post**

Want to increase the limitation of 18 pushpins when using a **GET** request.

**API Used:**

```
URL:http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/AerialWithLabels?zoomLevel=20&format=Jpeg&mapSize=640,500&key=MYKEY

Body:
pp=Latitude,longitude;iconstyle
..
..
pp=latitude,longitude;iconstyle //I have 100 pushpins
dc=l,FF007EFF,3;latitude1,longitude1_latitude2,longitude_2.....//I have the corresponding lines for all the push pins.
```

If I just draw the pushpins it works fine and I see the 100 push pins, but when I include the lines it fails with:

```
"errorDetails": [
        "Your request could not be completed because there was a problem with the service."
    ],
  "resourceSets": [],
    "statusCode": 500
```

But if I delete enough coordinates in the "dc=l.." parameter to draw exactly 62 lines or less it works fine I see 100 pushpins but not all the lines.

Does anyone know if there is a limitation on how many lines can we draw on the static map? I looked at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/get-a-static-map) it only says the limitation on pushpins but not on lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the request that fails, how long is the URL? GET URLs would potentially be long and browsers have a limit of 2083 characters for URL lengths. You could try encoding the line coordinates to make the URL shorter. I'm not sure about Bing Maps limitation on POS T, I don't see anything documented around this.

Another option is to take a look at Azure Maps, another Microsoft mapping platform. It also has a service for creating static map images. For large data sets you can create a GeoJSON file and upload that to the platform and have the static service render that data on the image. Here are some useful resources on this service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-render-custom-data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/render/getmapimage

Comment: Thanks for the information, I also think that encoding can solve my problem, and like you said there is no documentation about limitation on Post, if anyone is looking how to encode the coordinates here is the link provided by Microsoft which is a google document... https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm Unfortunately I cannot switch to Azure Maps right now.